# Python рекурсия, общая переменная

Tags: python, рекурсия

есть такая функция:

```
def foo():
    dosomething()
    foo()
```

нужно как-то сохранить результат всех вызовов dosomething() в одной переменной и вывести с помощью return в конце первого вызова функции foo()

я могу сделать так:

```
some_list = []
def foo(some_list):
    some_list = dosomething()
    foo(some_list)
print(some_list)
```

как обойтись без определения списка some_list вне функции foo() и вернуть результат return'ом?

Comment: Это архитектурная задача, и в твоём вопросе недостаточно информации. Скажи конкретней что ты хочешь сделать.

Comment: Всё равно полная чушь. Ты объявляешь глобальную переменную которую принтишь. В то же время у тебя есть какая-то загадочная рекурсивная функция, которая имеет локальную переменную с таким же именем, какое у глобальной. А ещё твоя рекурсивная функция получает аргумент, который не использует.

Ты можешь сказать что ты конкретно хочешь сделать? Скорее всего это решается одной строкой через reduce.

Comment: Возможно это поможет (с примером нормальной реализации рекурсии):

    def dosomething(count, some_list):
        return some_list + [count]
    def foo(count = 0, some_list = []):
        if count == 10:
            return some_list
        some_list = dosomething(count, some_list)
        return foo(count + 1, some_list)
    
    some_list = foo()
    print(some_list)

Или я не правильно понял задачу?

Comment: Вы ошиблись только с рекурсией, с ней все в порядке, просто я не стал расписывать весь код. Проблема была в том, что мне казалось, что если определить переменную some_list в параметрах функции, то при каждом вызове этой функции переменная some_list будет пустой, проще говоря устал :) Вам спасибо, решение проблемы найдено.

Answer (score 3):

НЕЛЬЗЯ делать так:

```
def foo(some_list = []):
    some_list = dosomething()
    foo(some_list)
    return some_list
print(foo())
```

после такого в some_list начнут накапливаться значения между вызовами, да но это все приведет к труднодиагностируемым ошибкам. 
Надо делать вот так:

```
 def foo(some_list = None):
        if some_list is None: some_list = [] 
        some_list = dosomething()
        some_list = some_list + foo(some_list)
        return some_list
    print(foo())
```

Comment: >> нужно как-то сохранить результат всех вызовов dosomething() в одной переменной

Если "всех" - это действительно всех, значит первый вариант решает задачу, а ваш - нет.

Ваш сохраняет результат вызова функции только в текущем контексте.

Чтобы это не приводило "к труднодиагностируемым ошибкам" необходимо просто понимать то, что инициализация дефолтных переменных происходит при запуске скрипта, а не при вызове функции. См. [здесь](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function)

Comment: Немного торопился - моя реализация не совсем верно работает - использую "общую переменную в рекурсии", но использую не во всю силу, так будет точнее:

    def dosomething(count, some_list):
        some_list += [count * 2]
    def foo(count = 0, some_list = []):
        if count == 3:
            return some_list
        dosomething(count, some_list)
        return foo(count + 1)

    print(foo()) # [0, 2, 4]
    print(foo()) # [0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4]

Теперь some_list хранит результат всех вызовов

Answer (score 0):

Вместо:

```
some_list = []
def foo(some_list):
    some_list = dosomething()
    foo(some_list)
print(some_list)
```

Нужно писать:

```
def foo(some_list = []):
    some_list = dosomething()
    foo(some_list)
    return some_list
print(foo())
```

Comment: См. ответ тов. @demmsnt и мои комментарии к его ответу.

Возможно я не правильно понял задачу, и тогда его ответ будет верным.
Если задачу я понял правильно, тогда надо использовать мои поправки - в первом моем ответе немного поторопился - работает наполовину правильно